# How do I set profile picture on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, user-profile

I'm using Lubuntu on my netbook and I want to change the LightDM greeter so i set the lightdm-webkit-greeter, but my user doesn't have a profile picture.

How I can set my profile picture?.

I have searched on

```
System > Users and Groups
```

But I can't find any option for this task.

Comment: All the above answers did not work for me. I solved this issue with the AccountService. [Link to the solution that solved my issue](https://github.com/lightblueseas/linuxstuff/wiki/Add-user-icon-in-lubuntu-to-login-screen)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest method is to save your profile picture manually.

**The steps are as follows:**

- Choose a picture you want to use.
- Optionally you can create one - preferably with equal dimensions (a square).
- Save the picture (in .PNG format) as `~/.face`.

Comment: agreed, this is the proper way to have your picture come up as the user specified

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It still shows the silver chess pawn guy.

Comment: What version of *buntu are you using and what login manager are you using?

Answer (score 6):

I'm new to **Lubuntu** (16.10) and here's how I did it:

1. Start
2. Under **System Tools** > select **LightDM GTK + Greeting Settings**
3. Click on the default avartar icon at the bottom of the popup window to choose:

   - **change icon**, or
   - **select file**

I got my icons from [flaticon.com](http://flaticon.com) (not in anyway affiliated, just a happy user).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1 and this is what I did to change my profile/login picture:

1. Select from menu "Settings Manager"
2. Select "About Me"
3. Click on the icon image and select "Browse"
4. Browse to the directory with your picture and select it.